# How to specify the time precision for a comparison

Tags: c#, time, compare

I have two date values that are being returned, I then need to compare these to ensure lastWriteDate of the file has not been updated since caching.

The problem I've got is, the lastWriteDate has the milliseconds included, and the clientDate doesn't. So when compared, the lastWriteDate will always be greater if it is in the same second.

```
if (!(Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"] == null))
{
     DateTime clientDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"]);
     DateTime lastWriteDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(newImagePath);


     if (lastWriteDate <= clientDate)
     {
        //Code here not being reached
     }
 }
```

Those miliseconds aren't important for the comparison I'm making, so what would be the best way to compare these values without them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract one date from the other. THen you will end up with a TimeSpan object, of which you can simply check the number of seconds and ignore the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the milliseconds in this way:

```
if (lastWriteDate.AddMilliseconds(-lastWriteDate.Millisecond) <= clientDate)
{
    // ....
}
```

You could also create a `TimeSpan` and check if it's lower than your maximum:

```
TimeSpan diff = clientDate - lastWriteDate;
if (diff < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
{
    // ....
}
```